# Create stickerpack using only Telegram Bot Api (or telegram api)

Tags: telegram-bot

The documentation describes methods for creating packs through api, but using them I constantly encounter various kinds of errors, mainly when sending images in a request. In general, maybe someone had experience in creating sticker packs through api, and maybe someone would like to share it)))

*Update*

Forgot to say that I use postman to learn api. Below is an example of a **sticker file upload** request:

1. **request body**

[image: Postman Body]

2. **Headers**

[image: Headers]

3. **Request URI**

https://api.telegram.org/botBOT_TOKEN/uploadStickerFile

And response that i get:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 413,
    "description": "Request Entity Too Large"
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: @GioIacca9 bad requests, and they always associated with the file field

Comment: @GioIacca9 As an example, were "type of file mismatch", "there is no photo in the request", "there is no sticker in the request" etc. I just follow the documentation, but nothing works(